# PHP turn comma into a <br />

Tags: php, mysql, line-breaks

I do know that php can turn a newline into a `<br />` using [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php), but is there a way that it can turn a comma (`,`) into a `<br />`?

For instance on an HTML page a user enters a bunch of words that are separated by a comma. He then submits it, it gets sent to a PHP file like normal and instead of the data getting sent right into the database, it goes through some kind of function to replace the commas with `<br />`.

So if I were to show the data on an HTML page, each thing they entered in that was separated by a comma is now separated by a newline/line break?

Comment: `$input = str_replace(',','<br />.',$input);` essentially?

Comment: str_replace!! yes! I couldn't think of what this was called, biggest mind blank, long time since I've used PHP. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have enough rep to vote your comment up.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace any string by another, so also a comma with a `<br />`:

```
$output = str_replace(',', '<br />', $input);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$output = str_replace(',', "\n", $input);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$values = str_replace( ',', '<br />', $values );
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [**php.net : str_replace**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is what you need.